# How to condense n-1, n-2, ... in a for loop (matlab)?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix, iteration

I am looking to input criteria as the size of the matrix decreases each time.

I have tried to simplify what I am doing to see if condensing it is even feasible.

Would there be a way to simplify the following so n-1, n-2, and so on is not needed and the code could adapt to the input matrix.

```
a = [2 4 5 6; 7 5 3 5; 6 7 9 4];
a
n = length(a(1,:));
b = [5];

for i = n,

    a = a.*b;

    a(:,n-1)=[];

    a

    a = a.*b;

a(:,n-2)=[];

a

a = a.*b;

a(:,n-3)=[];

a

end
```

I want to be able to see the output at each iteration.
E.g.:

```
a =

     2     4     5     6
     7     5     3     5
     6     7     9     4


a =

    10    20    30
    35    25    25
    30    35    20


a =

    50   150
   175   125
   150   100


a =

   750
   625
   500
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a FOR loop with the syntax

```
for i = starting_index:increment:ending_index
```

to count *down* from n-1 to 1, as follows:

```
for i = n-1:-1:1 % Count down from n-1 to 1
    a = a.*b;
    a(:,i)=[];
    a
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
a = [2 4 5 6; 7 5 3 5; 6 7 9 4]

n = size(a,1);
b = [5];
for i=1:n
    a = a(:,end-1).*b
end
```

I don't have access to Matlab right now, so it may not work as you intend to.

Comment: I have omitted the semicolon at lines where 'a' is defined in order to show the partial results at the console.

Comment: Works great! Thanks! Just had to change the second-to-last line to: a = a(:,end).*b , would not run with end-1

Comment: You are correct, the last loop will give an error when i==n (column end-1 does not exist).  In your example, you were removing the second to last column, so keep the end-1 but change the for i=1:n to n-1.